# Php retrieving number from database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a newbie to php still.
I'm using phpmyadmin as my database. I have a table called 'lessonno' and a column named 'lesson' in it. I tried using this code to retrieve out the number inside 'lesson'. But it's not printing out anything. Can someone help?

```
<?php 
$server = 'localhost'; 
$username = ''; 
$password = ''; 
$database = 'project'; 
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());


$sql = "SELECT 'lesson' FROM 'lessonno'";
$lesson = $_POST['lesson']; 
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $lesson; $i++) {    
echo "<div>
    <a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$i."\"><span>Lesson ".$i."</span></a>           
</div>
<br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: when you execute the select query inside phpmy admin,didd u get any value?

Comment: did u check whether $lesson is getting the value or not?

Comment: try to `die(mysql_error())` like `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and see what is the error comes

Comment: you are printing `$i`, which is loop index!! There isn't any use of `$result` here, then how will you get it??

Comment: you are not using any variable to fetch the result.

Comment: it's totaly unclear flow of code.. `$lession = $_POST['lesson']`!! I think it should be `count($result)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT lesson FROM lessonno";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['lesson'];
}
```

If you would like to only print out a specific lesson with an certan ID, you can use something along the lines:

```
$id = $_GET['lessonid']; // If you would have something like index.php?lessonid=36 and you'd like it to only fetch the data for the lesson with the id of 36. 
$sql = "SELECT lesson FROM lessonno WHERE id='$id'";
```

(by looking at the `$_POST['lesson']` part, I suppose that's something you might be trying to do as it's in the for loop as well)

Also, I suggest you use mysqli.

And, this:

```
echo "<div>
    <a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$i."\"><span>Lesson ".$i."</span></a>           
</div>
<br>";
```

Will just echo the $i as both lesson= and the span with Lesson, which won't grab any information from the actual database but just go with the current number it's at, from the for loop you have.

Comment: `Also, I suggest you use mysqli.`: Using `mysqli` with that unsafe string interpolated query will be as bad as using `mysql`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I never said that he should use it with this specific query. I'm just saying that he should get into using mysqli instead of mysql, and if he does that he might also get into how he should do the queries. :)

Answer (score 1):

i have made some changes in your code try this

```
<?php 
$server = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$database = 'project'; 
$conn = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die(mysql_error());


$sql = "SELECT `lesson` FROM `lessonno`";
$lesson = $_POST['lesson']; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $lesson_no = $row['lesson'];
echo "<div>
    <a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$lesson_no."\"><span>Lesson ".$lesson_no."</span></a>           
</div>
<br>";
    }

?>
```

**Note :** `mysql_*` is deprecated. use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Comment: @SKRocks I'm not sure why but it keep displaying this error message "Notice: Undefined index: lesson in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\k1levelselect.php on line 23"

Comment: @Chunkeat have you `lesson` column in your table `lessonno`

Comment: @SKRocks Yes i have the lesson column in my table lessonno

Comment: @Chunkeat check there is space in in column lesson before name or after? you can check this by execute query in your phpmyadmin directly

Answer (score 0):

For getting Values from DB you need to use something like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 print_r($row);   
}
```

For further reference please visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

For counting the number of data in your database, just insert this code

```
$sql = "SELECT 'lesson' FROM 'lessonno'";
$lesson = $_POST['lesson']; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);//this will count the number of rows in your table.

echo "<div>
<a href=\"k1levelX.php?lesson=".$count."\"><span>Lesson ".$count."</span></a>           
</div>
<br>";
```